# Mysql did not start

Tags: mysql

I tried to restart mysql. However it did not restart. Here is the content of mysql.log:

```
131217 17:01:09  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
131217 17:01:11  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 153229469
131217 17:01:11 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

131217 17:01:11 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
131217 17:01:11 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
131217 17:01:11 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131217 17:01:11 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131217 17:01:11 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131217 17:01:11 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
131217 17:01:11 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
^G/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibsMvrkL' (Errcode: 13)
131217 17:01:11  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
131217 17:01:11 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
131217 17:01:11 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
131217 17:01:11 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
131217 17:01:11 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Can any one help me to find the reason of this? In fact mysql was working before this time and it seems that it is not a regular error!!Please let me know if any other information is nedeed.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Given the specific error - share the output of both `df -h` and `mount` without parameters. Your `/tmp` mount is probably either full or mounted read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if there is a problem about your disk partition. May be its out of space or have a problem. The error clearly shows the problem is caused by creating temp file failure. Rest is listed because InnoDB failed to initialize.

Comment: You also could suffer a run out of inodes in a partition (note you can have en enough free space, but not enough inodes). You can check this with df -ih

Answer (score 0):

This error clearly mentioned that MySQL daemon unable to create a temporary file under /tmp directory.

Please check the permission of /tmp directory.

Your /tmp directory permission should have a sticky bit. below is the example for same.

```
drwxrwxrwt   3 root root 4.0K Feb  4 13:48 tmp
```